# iOS - Remote notification not working

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications, swift4, ios11

I have a very unique situation here, I have to test devices with same specification. The application i have developed has push notification capability enabled. All configurations are done in server side i.e added device as development device, the device is added into provisioning profile, the provisioning profile is installed in phone and development machine as well. Now the problem is the application is installed in both the device in one device everything works perfectly fine the notification appears for every event, however in another device it doesn't.

I tried everything i.e checking the setting in device if for some reasons notification is not allowed or may be some settings. I compared all the settings in both the devices everything is same.

The error I get in server side is `Bad Device Token` for one device. I tried to delete the token from server side and got it again still same situation it works for one device but not for other.

Any help or pointer would be really appreciated.

Comment: How did you install the App on the devices? Are you building from the code or downloading from TestFlight? Are the binaries signed with the same scheme? DEBUG or PRODUCTION?

Comment: I installed the app into both phone directly using the lightning cable. There is only one scheme and binary which is signed using development certificate.

Comment: Uhmm.. maybe the server-side is replacing the device token field. Are you testing the App with the same "user account"?

Comment: Yes I am testing the app with same user account, I don't understand why server side be biased for one iPhone?

Comment: Can you debug the device token? Compare with the database and console of the Xcode.

Comment: Did that and database token and xCode console token both are same. Still no notification on that device.

Comment: @Jeet Do you have any other application that we can test it for push?